# Error in enumerate when converting MarqueeLabel to Swift 1.2 Syntax

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uilabel

I want to add marquee effect to labels in my app written in Swift 1.2. I found this library [MarqueeLabel Swift](https://github.com/cbpowell/MarqueeLabel-Swift) but which is in Swift 2.
I converted almost all the errors except one.

The only error that shows now is:

> '[(layer: CALayer, anim: CAKeyframeAnimation)]' does not have a member
>   named 'enumerate'

The error showing code is :

```
// Call scroller
    var scrolls = scroller(interval: interval, delay: delay)
    // Perform all animations in scrolls
    for (index, scroll) in scrolls.enumerate() {
        let layer = scroll.layer
        let anim = scroll.anim

        // Add callback to single animation
        if index == 0 {
            anim.setValue(completion as AnyObject, forKey: MarqueeKeys.CompletionClosure.rawValue)
            anim.delegate = self
        }

        // Add animation
        layer.addAnimation(anim, forKey: "position")
    }
```

Please help me to correct it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swift 1.2 uses this syntax:

```
for (index, scroll) in enumerate(scrolls) {
```